# Why method `close` in StringWriter, PrintWriter has no effect?

Tags: java

Why in this classes (`StringWriter`, `PrintWriter`) method `close` has no effect as it mentioned in javadoc?

I understand that the simple not implemented I suppose. But why?

Comment: And what effect would you like to have on a `StringWriter`? `PrintWriter.close()` *has* an effect, BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `close()` method on a `StringWriter` doesn't do anything because there isn't anything that *needs* to be done.

Now we can contrast that with other types of `Writer` (etcetera) that do need to do something at "close" time.  For example:

- A `BufferedWriter` needs to flush any buffered output ... so that it doesn't get lost.
- A `FileWriter` needs to perform a close on the native file handle for the open open file.  That needs to be done because if these handles are not closed, the JVM will run out, and "opens" will stop working.
- But a `StringWriter` doesn't needs to do anything ... so it doesn't.

The `StringWriter::close()` method exists because it is actually implemented in its superclass.

The method exists in the superclass to *make* it (more) usable in polymorphic contexts.  If `close()` was not implemented in `Writer`, then there would be two "kinds" of `Writer` (closeable and non-closeable) and application code that used writers would need to handle them differently.

As it is, applications can close *all* `Writer` objects, knowing that the right thing will  be done.  In some situations, the JIT compiler can optimize away a call to `StringWriter::close()`.  In others, the overhead of a call to a no-op methods is rarely significant from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 6):

`StringWriter` doesnt have any resources on the file system unlike `PrintWriter`. It's `close` method just exists to satisfy the `Closable` interface.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't have any resources`. It has some data in, isn't it?

Comment: It has data in memory but it doesn't use a `PrintStream` to write the data to disk...

Comment: @user1432980 How would you "close" a `String`?