# Java try with resources on parameters

Tags: java, try-catch

this is a stupid question, but I can't figure it out.
Do I need to close Object passed as parameters inside a try with resources ?

here it is an example:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)) {
    ...
}
```

Do I need to call

```
sw.close();
```

after the try block ? or does it close automatically all the Autocloseable objects passed as parameters ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27963137/584862

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implicit invocation of `close` on your `PrintWriter` will actually close the underlying `Writer` as well.

See following example:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            System.out.println("closed");
        }
};
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)) {};
```

**Output**

```
closed
```

Answer (score 2):

`PrintWriter`'s `close` method will close `StringWriter` as well (but... yes, there is nothing to close there). It is not a common case for other wrappers.

You can pass both objects in `try` block to make sure they will be closed:

```
try (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: thanks, that was a possibile solution too... but will make code little less readable.

Answer (score 2):

Since both of these two classes implement `AutoClosable` interface, you can try:

```
try(
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)
) { ... }
```

It will automatically close both of these objects.

Answer (score 1):

Add a finally block and close objects passed.This is because finally block is always executed whether there is an exception or not.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)) {
    ...
}finally{
 sw.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple items inside try-with-resources initialization block:

```
try (final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)) {
    // ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Both of them will be closed automatically.